# The filter :even works... but :nth-child(2) doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

Edit:
I finally got a solution to my problem - I was using the wrong code for what I was wanting to achieve. Instead of ':nth-child' I should have used 'filter'.

here's the code I should have used:

```
$('div [class^="thirdCredits"]').filter(function(index) {
return (index % 2 == 1);
}).css("border" , "1px red solid");
```

......
http://jsfiddle.net/focusonfiddle/YVw6F/2/
Hello,
since my last message above I have now supplied more code. The code below works, but if you bring in the commented out code containing :nth-child(2n) it will not - what's going on?
Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>untitled</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("document").ready(function() {
//$.each($('[class^="thirdCredits"]:nth-child(2n)') ,function()     
$.each($('[class^="thirdCredits"]:even') ,function() 
{
    $(this).css("border" , "1px red solid");

    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="tableMarkup">
  <div id="myTable"></div>
  <div id="template">
    <ul style="width:65%; background-color:#67c1fd">
      <li>This is a line of text</li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="width:9%;">
      <li>
        <div class="styled-select">
          <select class="thirdCredits0">
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="width:9%;">
      <li>
        <div class="styled-select">
          <select class="thirdCredits1">
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="width:9%;">
      <li>
        <div class="styled-select">
          <select class="thirdCredits2">
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="width:9%;">
      <li>
        <div class="styled-select">
          <select class="thirdCredits3">
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nth-child(2) just grabs the 2nd child

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: You forgot to explain what "doesn't work" means. You also forgot to read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/). Why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally got a solution to my problem - I was using the wrong code for what I was wanting to achieve. Instead of ':nth-child' I should have used 'filter'.

Here's the code I should have used:

```
$('div [class^="thirdCredits"]').filter(function(index) {
return (index % 2 == 1);
}).css("border" , "1px red solid");
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot answer what is happening differently without seeing your HTML, but `:even` is not the same as `nth-child(2)` - perhaps you want `nth-child(2n)`?

If your HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Running this code:

```
$('li:even').each(function() { console.log($(this).text()); });
```

Would log "a", "c", "e", "2", "4" - it simply takes all the matching elements and gives you every other one.

While this code:

```
$('li:nth-child(2)').each(function() { console.log($(this).text()); });
```

Would log "b", "2" - only the 2nd child of each parent.

[The jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) has a nice little script that illustrates the differences.

Comment: Hi Paolo Bergantino thanks for your answer - I have supplied more code as I still haven't got things working.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/oriwuc/2/edit

**HTML:**

```
<div class="thirdCredits">1</div>
<div class="thirdCredits">2</div>
<div class="thirdCredits">3</div>
<div class="thirdCredits">4</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
console.log("This will output even ones with index of 0, 2, 4");

$.each($('[class^=thirdCredits]:even') ,function() { 
       console.log($(this).text());
});

console.log("This will output the second child only");

$.each($('[class^=thirdCredits]:nth-child(2)') ,function() { 
       console.log($(this).text());
});

console.log("This will output every 2nd child 2, 4, 6 etc.");

$.each($('[class^=thirdCredits]:nth-child(2n)') ,function() { 
       console.log($(this).text());
});
```

**jQuery( ":even" )**

> In particular, note that the 0-based indexing means that,
>   counter-intuitively, :even selects the first element, third element,
>   and so on within the matched set.

**jQuery( ":nth-child(index/even/odd/equation)" )**

```
index: The index of each child to match, starting with 1, the string even or odd, or an equation ( eg. :nth-child(even), :nth-child(4n) )
```

Comment: Hi KingKongFrog thanks for your answer - I have supplied more code as I still haven't got things working - I'm fairly new to Jquery, thanks.